# Autocomplete with PHP, MySQL and Jquery not sorting correctly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sorting

I use this script

https://github.com/daveismyname/autocomplete

Works good, but the sort is not what I need. I want to start searching by the number I type in.

See my picture to explain, it's self explanatory...
[sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYZCW.png)

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
$return_arr = array();
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM maerkte WHERE id LIKE :term LIMIT 10');
    $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $return_arr[] =  $row['id'];
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

}

How can I sort the query to the number I type first?

Thank you.

Comment: sorry, figured out right now i see the code in this post :( i'm sorry...

$stmt->execute(array('term' => $_GET['term'].'%'));

was the solution

Comment: That's in your question now. If that works, can always delete this unless you've got a solution to add as a self-answer.